# Google Spreadsheet getColor java

Tags: java, gdata

I using "com.google.gdata" for download and read google spreadsheet.
I want to read the cell color.
How can I do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's "write my code for me" question

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Find it in the [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#setBackgroundColor).